# Expo Linking back to App

Tags: javascript, react-native, deep-linking, expo

I have been using Expo to develop a react-native app, The functionality I am currently trying to implement is to share a link with friends on any platform and when they click this link it will launch my app.

After extensive research online - I've come to a blocker, following [expo's documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/linking.html) I defined a scheme for my app - when I press share everything works correctly a message is created and I'm able to share content but only as string.

I am using react-natives Share library to share to an app and I'm using Expo to provide me with the link.

Ideally my first goal is to get the app opening using the Expo Link before I explore further into adding more functionality to the link.

```
Share.share({
    message: "Click Here to View More! " + Expo.Linking.makeUrl() ,
    url: Expo.Linking.makeUrl(),
    title: 'Sufiyaan has invited you to join this activity',
  })
  .then((result) =>{
    console.log(result)
      if(result === 'dismissedAction'){
        return
      }
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(error))
```

In the root of my app I have also defined the event handlers: App.js

```
handleOpenURL(event) {
  if (event.url && event.url.indexOf(scheme + '://') === 0) {
      crossroads.parse(event.url.slice(scheme.length + 3));
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  let scheme = 'nxet'
  Expo.Linking.getInitialURL()
    .then(url => {
      console.log("App.js getInitialURL Triggered")
      // this.handleOpenURL({ url });
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
  Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  Linking.removeEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
}
```

When I share the link to Whatsapp, Facebook Messenger or even just messages or notes it appears as myapplink://, I try to enter this into the browser and instead of asking me to open my app - it does a google search.

Please note I am attempting this on an Android Device.

Is there something I am doing incorrectly?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I am having an issue getting Expo.Linking to work, which version of expo are you using? Thanks!

Comment: Hey Greg, I recently upgraded Expo to SDK V28.0.0, I decided that I would pursue to use Branch instead of Linking although the functionality isn't the same as what Linking was supposed to provide - it would be worth exploring -  Expo has configured it and in the new release Expo have done an update to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

According to this:
https://docs.expo.io/versions/v28.0.0/workflow/linking#__next

You need to provide a link to your own website which then redirects to the slug:// link for your app in order for gmail and other android apps to work.